# Still progressing in Excel and CSV, and I can't really edit Excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

## Code:

```
#Load the file by name
food_price = opxl.load_workbook('Food.xlsx')
sheet_food = food_price['Sheet1']
#Specify position
acell = sheet_food['a1'] 
#Specify number position of cell.
cell2 = sheet_food.cell(2, 3)
for row in range(2, sheet_food.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet_food.cell(row, 3)
    correct_price = cell.value * 0.85
    correct_price_cell = sheet_food.cell(row, column = 3)
    correct_price_cell.value = correct_price_cell

food_price.save("Food.xlsx")
```

I wanted to add a column in the spreadsheet, but it seems to block me from doing it.

## Error:

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 199, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert <Cell 'Sheet1'.C2> to Excel
```

PLEASE help, since I'm a newbie to spreadsheet editing.
I will have lots of gratefulness towards the answers and the advice I will get.
Thanks, Stack Overflow!
[image: This is the excel file "Food" I'm talking to.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
food_price = opxl.load_workbook('Food.xlsx')
sheet_food = food_price['Sheet1']
#Specify position
acell = sheet_food['a1'] 
#Specify number position of cell.
cell2 = sheet_food.cell(2, 3)
for row in range(2, sheet_food.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet_food.cell(row, 3)
    if  cell.value  :
        correct_price = cell.value * 0.85
        correct_price_cell = sheet_food.cell(row,  3)
        correct_price_cell.value = correct_price

food_price.save("Food.xlsx")
```

Comment: I just used this a couple of times, and it works out great, thanks a lot!